# Validate request payloads and responses against a given OpenApi/Swagger specification

Tags: json, validation, swagger, openapi

We have an HTTP API which is written with the [hug framework for Python](http://www.hug.rest/) but this is not set in stone and could be replaced with something else in the future.

Next to it, we have manually written an [OpenApi/Swagger 2.0 specification file](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification) in YAML for that API in order to provide interactive documentation. However, both are not connected to each other by [any of the tooling](https://swagger.io/open-source-integrations/) from the Swagger ecosystem - when we make changes in the API, we make the same changes in the specification and vice versa (which is not ideal but we might improve on this later).

Now, for the sake of integration testing, we would like to take a few static requests and their payloads (JSON and multipart/form-data) as well es responses (JSON) and validate if they fit the models from our specification file.

What could be an easy way to achieve this? I am open to any technology or programming language as long as complexity stays reasonable.

Answer (score 1):

For Open Api 3 documents, my colleagues and I had the same requirement and ended up writing our own command-line tooling to achieve this, I've open sourced it here: https://github.com/hevans90/oa3-api-defender

It will dynamically call any endpoints specified in the **paths** array of a specification, currently supporting GET, DELETE, POST, PATCH, PUT requests. It will dynamically create requests based on example values provided in the spec.

Query & Path example parameter values will be included in generated requests. Request bodies (in POSTs for example) are dynamically generated from example values in the requestBody object, in the spec.

To provide valid examples in your spec, [see this article](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/adding-examples/)