# How am I supposed to validate inputs in an YAML file that contains various POST requests? I have to use Python programming for it

Tags: python, validation, yaml, swagger

If I have to verify the username. What would be the procedure for that?

It is an API based on an `OpenAPI 2 (Swagger)` definition. I have absolutely no idea how to approach this task. I am supposed to check for the required parameters' presence and validate all the inputs in the API.

Comment: Can you provide more details about what you're trying to do? Are you developing an API based on an OpenAPI (Swagger) definition and want to automatically verify the operation parameters and request bodies against the constraints specified in the OpenAPI definition (i.e. presence of required parameters, their data types, etc.)? Or something else? The more details, the easier it is for others to help you.

Comment: Yes. That's exactly what I'm trying to do. I want to verify the presence of required parameters and data types for all the inputs. @Helen

Comment: See if this helps: [OpenApi 3 request validation with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54748710/113116), [Validate request payloads and responses against a given OpenApi/Swagger specification](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48338422/113116)

Comment: @Helen It is version 2.